# Why returns this curl function an undifined index at initial page load?

Tags: php, wordpress, curl

I'm using the function below to get the file size of images hosted in the Cloud.
I need to display this size on my page.
When the page is loaded the first time it returns a notice: Undefined index: content-length. When reloading the page, the notice disappears and the page is displayed fine. Why is this happening and what should I do about it?

```
$post_id = get_the_ID();
$post_thumbnail_id = get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id );

//retrieve the size in bytes

$filePath = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'full');
  if (filter_var($filePath, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)) {
    $ch = curl_init();
    $headers = [];
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $filePath);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    // this function is called by curl for each header received
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION,
    function($curl, $header) use (&$headers)
     {   
     $len = strlen($header);
     $header = explode(':', $header, 2);
     if (count($header) < 2) // ignore invalid headers
     return $len;

      $name = strtolower(trim($header[0]));
      if (!array_key_exists($name, $headers))
        $headers[$name] = [trim($header[1])];
      else
        $headers[$name][] = trim($header[1]);

        return $len;
       }  
    );
 $data = curl_exec($ch);
}

//convert the size in bytes to MB
$filemb = $headers['content-length']['0'] / 1000 / 1000;
$filemb = round($filemb,2);

// do my stuff
```

Comment: Looks like your CDN did not send a Content-Length header for those images on first request. (But doing this on every single page load is a rather bad idea to begin with, will slow your whole page down. You should find a way to cache those results.)

Comment: Nice to see my curl header function in use there :). @04FS is correct, the server is not sending the `Content-Length` header which is not mandatory. Also please be aware that `/ 1000 / 1000` is not correct to convert to MB, there is 1024 bytes in a KB, and 1024 KB in a MB. Technically it's MiB and KiB but when it comes to file storage the common convention is 1024 not 1000 even if the newer notation is not used.

Comment: @04FS, thanks. I thought that my function (and displaying the page) runs faster than retrieving the Content-Length but, as I'm not that experienced, I could be wrong. Easily. I have to rethink my way of doing things. It's all about products, served from the CDN, maybe I can store this value in the database at product creation.......

Comment: @Geoffrey. Yes, indeed, it is your function. When I posted this question I had searched from where I fetched the function, to give you credit, but could not find it quickly. I know that /1000/1000 is not the best math but somehow it is the only way to get the outcome consistent to my local system and Amazon S3,and the size downloading the full size image myself. Using /1024/1024 brings me a smaller file, inconsistent with the downloaded size. Whay? Beats me.....

Comment: @All who can help: It appears not reliable after all. Sometimes it is set and sometimes it don't, It looks like the $filemb variable is already set to 0 before the size could be retrieved. How can we solve it?

Comment: Clickint the Updat button on the product page is retrieving the filesize fine....

Answer (score 0):

Amongst other things I took the advice of 04FS and Geoffrey and worked out a different approach. I created a Custom Field (filesize) in WooCommerce and at product creation, I set the field with the value returned by the function above.

So, I'm storing it in my own database. Because of that, the page speed will not be decreased. I think it will also be beneficial for bandwidth usage.

So it is only retrieved once.

@04FS and @Geoffrey.... thanks!

**EDIT:**

It appears not reliable after all. Sometimes it is set and sometimes it don't> Have to figure that one out.....